# $H^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ functions vanish at infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces

If $f \in H^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ does this imply that $f(x) \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$?

I know that if $f $ is uniformly continuous then the answer is yes, but i'm not so sure about this case..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus and Cauchy-Schwarz, for $x>y$:
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \int_y^x |f'(t)|dt \leq \Vert f'\Vert_{L^2}|x-y|^{1/2}.
$$
Therefore, $f\in H^1$ implies $f$ uniformly continuous.

Comment: Why does the Fundamental theorem of calculus hold?

Comment: @fwd that’s the content of one of the Sobolev embeddings. $H^1(\Bbb{R})$ embeds into the Holder space $C^{1/2}(\Bbb{R})$. One way to argue is that this clearly holds for $f\in C^{\infty}_c(\Bbb{R})$. Then, by density of $C^{\infty}_c$ in $H^1$, we can find a sequence $\{f_j\}$ which converges to $f$ in $H^1$. Passing to a subsequence, we may assume it converges pointwise a.e as well. So, the above inequality holds for each $f_j$; so by taking the limit $j\to\infty$  on both sides, we get the desired claim for $f$ as well.

Comment: ok well strictly speaking my comment only shows that the inequality holds for $f\in H^1$ for a.e $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$. To show that a continuous redefinition of $f$ is possible, consider $F(x)=\int_{0}^xf’(t)\,dt$, and then with a little finessing, you can show this agrees a.e with $f$ up to a constant (which can then be offset by changing the base point $0$ to some other $x_0$), and hence $f$ has a continuous redefinition.